# Sonar review svn patch files

Tags: svn, sonarqube

I am new to Sonar. I would like to know if it can work on svn patch files (could be unpacked to temp folder) only. 
I understood that http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cutoff+Plugin does the similar sort of job. Any confirmation of that? or any other plugin that can help me achieve that?

Is there a simple way to modify Sonar source for what I am trying to achieve?
Are there other tools ,like Sonar, can work on svn patches

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Cutoff Plugin won't meet your needs. It only helps analysing only new file added on your scm tool since a given date.

To answer your question: Sonar can't analyse only diffs (or path files if you prefer). And I'm not sure you'll find a tool that can do that as diff files only contains excerpts from code, which makes them very difficult to analyse (the parser does not have the full context) and which will produce wrong results most of the time.

Comment: Would it be possible , if we get the actual latest changed files? It wont have all the source files in a project, or what might have been included or import in a C/java file but it can have full context of a C/Java file itself. Am I making any sense?

Comment: Yes, this could be possible, but you would have to tweak your process to do so. And you could probably not compile your code, which means that basically, you'd only be able to run static tools like Checkstyle or PMD that analyse source code (and not Findbugs which works on bytecode).

Comment: Thats exactly what i want, I dont want to use tool that need compilation. Just what defects i can find from static analysis.